# Memory reallocation - keep my data in place

Tags: c++, memory-management

Assuming I have some array in heap doesn't matter constructed by `malloc` or `new`. I need the most efficient way to enlarge it. I mean if it has enough free space which lying after already allocated data can I keep my data untouched. Is it possible to maintain in C++?

Does `realloc` work in such manner?

Comment: Yes, at least in most implementations, `realloc` will attempt to enlarge the current allocation rather than allocating a new block of memory and copying to it. `new` provides no analog to this (i.e., no way to even ask it to enlarge an allocation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `realloc` is what you are looking for. Note that it won't work with `new`, you will have to use `malloc` (or, say, `calloc`). Also, sometimes it is just impossible to extend memory, so `realloc` will try to do it for you, but if it couldn't — it will resort to allocating new memory, copying your contents to a new place and freeing the old memory.

Comment: You answer on my question even better than i defined it

Comment: It's strange and pity that modern C++-style memory management not provides desired features.

Comment: @triclosan: If you go down to physical & virtual memory details you will see why this is sometimes impossible. It has nothing to do with C++ — it is how hardware works. You just cannot jump over your head, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

yes, [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) works like that, though the link says that it is not guaranteed, I think this is for cases where memory is fragmented and there is not enough room to expand the memory block in-situ.